# How fill part of a circle using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

```
circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
r = diameter / 2
tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}
dat <- circleFun(c(1,-1),2.3,npoints = 100)
ggplot(dat,aes(x,y)) + geom_path(color="black") + ggtitle("circle")
```

I am plotting with ggplot2. I want to fill the circle with blue only in first quadrant. What should I do?

Thank you !

Comment: I don't think this question deserves the downvotes.  Yes, it requires only rather basic geometry knowledge to fix, but still the OP posted a reproducible example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
# Define the circle; add a point at the center if the 'pie slice' if the shape is to be filled
circleFun <- function(center=c(0,0), diameter=1, npoints=100, start=0, end=2, filled=TRUE){
  tt <- seq(start*pi, end*pi, length.out=npoints)
  df <- data.frame(
    x = center[1] + diameter / 2 * cos(tt),
    y = center[2] + diameter / 2 * sin(tt)
  )
  if(filled==TRUE) { #add a point at the center so the whole 'pie slice' is filled
    df <- rbind(df, center)
  }
  return(df)
}

#Define separate data frames for the filled and unfilled circle
quarterCircle <- circleFun(c(1,-1), diameter = 2.3, start=0., end=0.5, filled=TRUE)
fullCircle <- circleFun(c(1, -1), 2.3, start=0, end=2, filled=FALSE)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=quarterCircle, aes(x,y), color="black", fill="black") + 
  geom_path(data=fullCircle, aes(x, y), color="black") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

1. Use your knowledge of circle geometry and adapt the circle function to start and end at arbitrary points, in this case `0.5*pi` and `1.5*pi`
2. Use `geom_polygon` instead of `geom_path`

Like this:

```
circleFun <- function(center=c(0,0), diameter=1, npoints=100, start=0, end=2){
  tt <- seq(start*pi, end*pi, length.out=npoints)
  data.frame(
    x = center[1] + diameter / 2 * cos(tt),
    y = center[2] + diameter / 2 * sin(tt)
  )
}

dat <- circleFun(c(1,-1), 2.3, start=0.5, end=1.5)
ggplot(dat,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_polygon(color="black") + 
  ggtitle("half circle") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to fill the first quadrant with color and other parts of the graph remain the same as before. It seems you cut off other parts of the graph. Could you please modify your code a little bit to keep other parts of the graph? Thank you.

Comment: @TENGPENG, I think that if Andrie gave you the full code, you miss out on the fun of *learning*. There's a lot to learn from a little bit of exploration, and I think that Andrie gave you a great starting point to explore from here.