# Color a designated area?

Tags: r, geometry

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to color only half of a circle that I created using grid.circle.

```
    library(grid)
    grid.circle(x=.5, y=.5, r=.25,gp=gpar(lwd=10))
```

I want to make the top half blue, and the bottom half leave white.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: in what language are you working?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794596/how-fill-part-of-a-circle-using-ggplot2/12800110#12800110

Answer (score 5):

Using `grid.polygon()` and some basic trigonometry, you can define a function that'll do this

Some picky care needs to be taken so that the filled semicircle is not distorted when the viewport is non-square. To accomplish this in a way that matches the rules used by `grid.circle()`, I've set the origin in `"npc"` units, and the circle radius in `"snpc"` units. (For more on the meanings of `"npc"` and `"snpc"`, see `?unit` and `vignette("grid")`):

```
library(grid)

filledSemiCircle <- function(x_origin, y_origin, radius, fillcolor, top=TRUE) {
    theta <- seq(0, pi, length = 100)
    if(!top) theta <- theta + pi     ## To fill the bottom instead
    x <- unit(x_origin, "npc") + unit(cos(theta) * radius, "snpc")
    y <- unit(y_origin, "npc") + unit(sin(theta) * radius, "snpc")
    grid.polygon(x, y, gp = gpar(fill = fillcolor))
}

filledSemiCircle(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, "dodgerblue")
filledSemiCircle(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, "gold", top=FALSE)
grid.circle(x = .5, y=.5, r=.25,gp=gpar(lwd=10))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent work. This draws filled chords. A few simple modifications results in code that fulfills an item that has been unfilled  on Rhelp for about 5 years, namely how to build arcs that "line up with" or "fit inside" circles of specified center and radius. http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+grid.curve+arc#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20grid.curve%20arc+page:1+mid:7euwzo4gppfxnobx+state:results

Comment: @DWin -- Cool beans. I have to say I was pretty proud of this one myself. Also, my respect for Paul Murrel's excellent software craftsmanship just keeps growing.

Answer (score 2):

This is first draft of a modification to Josh's excellent work that creates filled chords:

```
filledArc <- function(x_origin, y_origin, radius, fillcolor, top=TRUE) {
    theta <- seq(0, pi/2, length = 100)
    if(!top) theta <- theta + pi     ## To fill the bottom instead
    x <- unit(x_origin, "npc") + unit(c(0, cos(theta) * radius, 0), "snpc")
    y <- unit(y_origin, "npc") + unit(c(0, sin(theta) * radius, 0), "snpc")
    grid.polygon(x, y, gp = gpar(fill = fillcolor))
}

filledArc(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, "lightgoldenrod")
filledArc(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, "blue", top=FALSE)
grid.circle(x = .5, y=.5, r=.25,gp=gpar(lwd=10))
```

[image]

I think it needs a bit of further work to make it parametrized by starting and ending theta (done):

```
filledArc2 <- function(x_origin, y_origin, radius, fillcolor, angle0, angle1) {
    theta.range <- seq(angle0, angle1, length = 100)
    x <- unit(x_origin, "npc") + unit(c(0, cos(theta.range) * radius, 0), "snpc")
    y <- unit(y_origin, "npc") + unit(c(0, sin(theta.range) * radius, 0), "snpc")
    grid.polygon(x, y, gp = gpar(fill = fillcolor))
}

filledArc2(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, "lightgoldenrod", 0,      pi/4)
filledArc2(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, "blue",           pi/4,   pi*(3/2) )
grid.circle(x = .5, y=.5, r=.25,gp=gpar(lwd=10))
```

[image]

Comment: It might also be nice to vectorize this, so that a single call to `filledArc()` (or `filledSemiCircle()`) could take vectors of x and y origins, plotting the same "symbol" at each point. (Not that you should do that -- I was certainly to lazy to do it my myself ;)

Comment: Agree. Probably should also allow a larger number of arguments to `gpar()` for the border and line widths, possibly using `...` or some other list-passing mechanism or `modifyList`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: I sent an email citing your work on this question to Paul Murrell.