# Display two colors inside a node in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot, igraph

Is it possible to display two colors inside a node instead of one in a network representation in R?

For example a node for which half of the circle is blue and half is red.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is there any code that you are working with right now?

Comment: I have not found anything yet. I am using the plot function but I am not sure I can change the vertex.color argument.

Comment: If you're using **grid** graphics, you might adapt [the code found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015110/color-a-designated-area/13015631#13015631). For **ggplot2**, [this might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794596/how-fill-part-of-a-circle-using-ggplot2/12800110#12800110).

Answer (score 4):

@Rodrigo is actually on the right track.

See:

```
library(igraph)
?vertex.shape.pie
```

Which allows things like:

```
test <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(one=1,two=1))
plot(
  test,
  vertex.shape="pie",
  vertex.pie=list(c(10,10)),
  vertex.pie.color=list(c("red","blue"))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
pie(c(1,1),init.angle=90)
```

I don't know if it can be adjusted to your needs, though.

Comment: The question is about the package `igraph`.